# Breadcrumb Angular 12

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs, angular12, xng-breadcrumb

I am working on my project and I want to add breadcrumb on top of every page and when I click on previous name of a page I want to redirect on that page. Version of Angular is 12.

[I researched on the internet and I found something what I need actually.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xng-breadcrumb)

I finished all steps and put in html file `<xng-breadcrumb></xng-breadcrumb>`

```
<div class="sdb-menu" id="sdb-menu">
  <ul class="menu grid-x" *ngIf="menu.length">
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" class="text-center menu-item" *ngFor="let item of menu">
      <a class="gigaaa_sidebar_item" [routerLink]="item.link" [queryParams]="{ type: item.query }">
        {{item.title}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="menu submenu grid-x" *ngIf="submenu.length">
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" class="text-center menu-item" *ngFor="let item of submenu">
      <a class="gigaaa_sidebar_item" [routerLink]="item.link">
        {{item.title}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <xng-breadcrumb></xng-breadcrumb>
</div>
```

[The error is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAhe7.png)

I really don't know what is the problem. Please help.

Comment: Welcome, please check [ask] You should provide a [mcve] as code blocks, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import it correctly in your app.module.ts? As shown in the Quick start section (2nd point) of its npm page?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xng-breadcrumb

Comment: Problem was in breadcrumb. After few hours, I check it again and everything is okay now.